# Why does SBCL (or Common lisp in general?) dislike my loop?

Tags: common-lisp

Recursive find-dir-upwards works as expected, but find-dir-upwards-loop refuses to compile, complaining about type mismatch (even with added type annotations) under SBCL (Win64, Portacle 1.4, SBCL 2.0.0).

What did I do wrong ?

```
(defun find-dir-upwards-loop (dir marker-file)
  (loop for prev = nil then curr
        for curr = dir then (uiop:pathname-parent-directory-pathname curr)
        until (equal curr prev)
        with f = (merge-pathnames marker-file curr)
        when (uiop:file-exists-p f) return curr))

(defun find-dir-upwards (dir marker-file)
  (let ((f (merge-pathnames marker-file dir)))
    (if (uiop:file-exists-p f)
        dir
        (let ((parent (uiop:pathname-parent-directory-pathname dir)))
          (unless (equal dir parent)
            (find-dir-upwards parent marker-file))))))
```

Comment: Please post the error message.

Comment: try macroexpanding the loop to see how it is translated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't (portably) put a `with` after an `until`.  Look at the grammar in the [Hyperspec](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_loop.htm#loop):

> loop [name-clause] {variable-clause}* {main-clause}* => result*

`With` is a `variable-clause`, but `until` is a `termination-test`, which is a `main-clause`.  All `main-clause`s must come after all `variable-clause`s.

Comment: Thanks, inlining the merge-pathnames call / getting rid of the with still looks better than using let, and it works.

Answer (score 3):

**The *WITH after FOR* part of the answer:**

```
(loop for x = 0 then (+ x 1)
      with y = (+  x 1)
      when (> x 10) return (list x y))
```

This is a sequence of events:

1. the `X` variable will be established
2. the `Y` variable will be established and initialized to `(+ x 1)`
3. the `X` variable will be set to `0`
4. ...

As you can see, in *operation 1)* `X` will be a variable, but it won't be initialized to `0`. This would happen in *operation 3)*. Thus in *operation 2)* `X` will not have been initialized to `0`  -> its value might be `NIL`. Adding `1` to `NIL` is an error.

Comment: Thanks, super helpful. It's interesting that '.. for x from 0 to 10' does both create and initialize x before the WITH clause. (Or at least, in my stack, similar to OP).

Answer (score 0):

#### Simplified code

After some while thinking, I realized you can simplify your original function to:

```
(defun find-dir-upwards (dir marker-file)
  (let ((parent (uiop:pathname-parent-directory-pathname dir)))
    (unless (equal dir parent)
      (if (probe-file (merge-pathnames marker-file dir))
          dir
          (find-dir-upwards parent marker-file)))))
```

And its correspoding loop function is:

```
(defun find-dir-upwards (dir marker-file)
  (loop for parent = (uiop:pathname-parent-directory-pathname dir)
        unless (equal dir parent)
        do (if (probe-file (merge-pathnames marker-file dir))
               (return dir)
               (setf dir parent))))
```

As @Rezo pointed out in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53808518/clozure-common-lisp-file-exists-p-is-undefined), `probe-file` is portable between different Common Lisp implementations, while `uiop:file-exists-p` is not.

#### Original answer

I would define the loop differently.

Use the `(let ((dir dir)) (loop ... (setf dir (<some updater function>))))` idiom to have some reference variable(s) which are updated every run through the loop - until the condition is met.

```
(defun find-dir-upwards (dir marker-file)
  (let ((f (merge-pathnames marker-file dir))
        (dir dir))
    (loop for parent = (uiop:pathname-parent-directory-pathname dir)
          unless (equal dir parent)
          do (if (uiop:file-exists-p f) ;; if marker-file in dir
                 (return dir)           ;; then arrived at destination
                 (progn
                   (setf dir parent)    ;; otherwise climb up one dir-level
                   (setf f (merge-pathnames marker-file dir)))))))
```

Which is then further dissectable to:

```
(defun marker-file-in-dir-p (dir marker-file)
  (uiop:file-exists-p (merge-pathnames marker-file dir)))

(defun find-dir-upwards (dir marker-file)
  (let ((dir dir))
    (loop for parent = (uiop:pathname-parent-directory-pathname dir) ;; parent from dir
          unless (equal dir parent)
          do (if (marker-file-in-dir-p dir marker-file)
                 (return dir)
                 (setf dir parent)))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the probe-file pointer. [After Svante pointed out why it was bugging out,] Inlining merge-pathnames call instead of introducing the f binding (would be uglier using let) made it work while still looking pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Something about combining the step form of 'FOR' and a 'WITH' creates this problem. IT seems like it tried to initialize the 'with' before the 'for' creates x, but, not always. I haven't solved it, but I have had this issue before. For example:

```
(loop for x = 0 then (+ x 1)
      with y = (+  x 1)
      when (> x 10) return (list x y))

Yields:

Value of X in (+ X 1) is NIL, not a NUMBER.
   [Condition of type SIMPLE-TYPE-ERROR]

Restarts:
 0: [RETRY] Retry SLIME REPL evaluation request.
 1: [*ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.
 2: [ABORT] abort thread (#<THREAD "new-repl-thread" RUNNING {10044CC083}>)

Backtrace:
  0: (SB-C::%COMPILE-TIME-TYPE-ERROR (NIL) NUMBER #<unused argument> (X) "(+ X 1)" NIL)
  1: ((LAMBDA ()))
  2: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (LOOP FOR X = 0 THEN ...) #<NULL-LEXENV>)
  3: (EVAL (LOOP FOR X = 0 THEN ...))
 --more--
```

But removing either the step form, or the with, seems to work fine:

```
CL-USER> (loop for x from 0 to 10
              with y = (+  x 1)
              collect (list x y))
((0 1) (1 1) (2 1) (3 1) (4 1) (5 1) (6 1) (7 1) (8 1) (9 1) (10 1))
CL-USER> (loop for x = 0 then (+ x 1)
              when (> x 10) return x)
11
```